# How to replicate SublimeText ctrl+D in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext2

I am used to work with Sublime text and trying to switch for Visual Studio for bigger projects, one of the feature of sublime that I absolutely love is its multiple select feature. You can hit ctrl + d multiple times to select next instance of the same word and then rewrite them all at once. Is there anything like this in Visual studio? I tryed to find it, but with no success.

Btw I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## Visual studio 2017-19

The default shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

---

### But if you want to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

- Go to the menu **Tools > Options** then select the **Keyboard** tab on the left

  At the top you'll find an option to add extra keybindings, select **Visual Studio Code**. Save and That's it!
  [image: Setting]

  This works because **Visual Studio Code** has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and other shortcuts similar to **SublimeText**

#### Alternatively you can manually add shortcuts

In the image, you can find any command to customize in the middle section.

The particular command you are interested is the one selected `Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret`

Comment: Thanks, that is exacly what I was looking for!

Comment: That's exactly what CTR+D in sublime is doing. Great.

Answer (score 2):

**Ctr R, R**, this is used to replace the name of the varibals, depronto can serve it.

and you are encouraged here are all the shortcuts of vs2015 http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/

Answer (score 1):

- Goto Tools / Options / Keyboard
- Search for duplicate
- Choose Edit.Duplicate
- Remove the assignement for the current shortcut
- Assign the shortcut you want

[image]

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. They asked for multi select

Answer (score 0):

Use **Alt +leftClick** and **ctrl+F2** . For more reference you can go Official Website [link]https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference

Comment: Thats not it.. I dont wana rename every instance of it. For instance, lets say I have 2 vectors and use resize on them on two consucutive lines, and now I want to change it to reserve, I would just clickd ctrl+d twice on first resize, it would select me both texts in sublime text and I would rewrite them... But it would not change every resize to reserve. I guess Visual studio just does not have this functionality. And again, Visual Studio Code is NOT the same as Visual Studio 2015, and does not have the same shortcuts (it even seems like visual studio code can do this with ctrl D)

Comment: Seems like find and replace via cltr H is the only option.. It just does not seem as elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use this Visual Studio Extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.SublimeVS

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + Shift + L seems to work.

Comment: That works like ctrl+L for me, which delets the whole line.

Comment: Weird! Should work, and it does for me. Here's their doc with all the shortcuts. https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: Just a question, did you install any keymap? Or did you customize at any time the default shortcuts?

Comment: Nope, I haven't. Fast google search shows that Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 201x are completely different softwares tho, so thats why it does not work :)